# Call a hook in a condition

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm using React Query to query my data and I have a hook "useDraft" that I only want to call if a condition is met.

```
const getDraft = useDraft;
let draft;

if (category === "drafts") {
   const { data } = getDraft({
      id: id,
   });
   draft = data;
   projectId = draft && draft.projectId;
}
```

If I go from one place where the condition is met to another I get one of these errors (depending on which way I'm going):

`Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.` or `Rendered fewer hooks than expected.`

Anyone who knows how can I solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Read this please https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: if you want to check a condition, might as well pass a function reference that will resolve the condition into your hook, and you can check that condition inside the hook, without calling the hook itself a inside a condition, which is wrong and will produce unexpected bugs.

Comment: That's a good idea! Thanks @Anuja

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation linked in one of the comments, hooks should be called consistently (i.e. always and in the same order) inside your component and not conditionally.

You could solve it by having the hook return the draft and a function. You'd then call the hook at the top of your component and later call the function returned by the hook conditionally to load the draft.

For example (assuming the draft comes from some API):

```
function useDraft(){
  const [draft, setDraft] = useState();
  return [
    draft,
    (params) => {
      fetch(/* whatever */)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(draft => {
          setDraft(draft);
        });
    }
  ];
}

function MyComponent(){
  const [draft, loadDraft] = useDraft();
  const projectId = draft && draft.projectId;

  if (category === "drafts") {
    loadDraft({id: id});
  }
}
```